# Ruby and Websockets

Tags: ruby, curl, websocket

I'm trying to create an asynchronous connection to a device that broadcasts packets when something changes, like a door is opened. I want to process the feedback in realtime to the control system. I also need to try to do this with the standard library due to the limitations on some controllers.

Right now I've been using cURL inside ruby to keep a connection open and reconnect if it disconnects. That has worked fine, but on macOS Big Sur after a few days terminal stops working due to the requests. I have not been able to figure out why.

I've rewritten most of my script to use net/http instead of cURL, but I can't figure out keeping a connection open and then real-time sending data to another function.

cURL Ruby Code:

```html
def httpBcast(cmd, url, header,valuesListID,valuesListFID)
    fullCommand = "curl -s -k -X #{cmd} '#{url}' #{header}"
    loop do
        begin
            PTY.spawn( fullCommand ) do |stdout, stdin, pid|
                begin
                    # Send Output to Savant
                    stdout.each { |line| parseBcast(line,valuesListID,valuesListFID)}
                rescue Errno::EIO
                    puts "Errno:EIO error, but this probably just means " +
                                "that the process has finished giving output"
                end
            end
        rescue PTY::ChildExited
            puts "The child process exited!"
        end
    end
end

def parseBcast(msg='',valuesListID,valuesListFID)
    if msg.start_with?("data:")
        msg.gsub!(/\n+/, '')
        msg.gsub!(/\s+/, "")
        msg.gsub!("data:","")
        msg.to_json
        msgP = JSON.parse(msg)
        if valuesListFID.include?(msgP['result']['deviceId'])
            id = valuesListFID.index(msgP['result']['deviceId'])
            id +=1
        else
            id = "Device Doesn't Exist"
        end
        msgP['result']['deviceId'] = id
        send_savant msgP.to_json
        
    end
end
```

Any guidance anyone can offer would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the vendor needed to make a firmware update. All Good Now.